# Getting 404 error when calling php file in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, localhost, react-dom

I have created a simple contact form and using php via ajax.
I passed the url like: /api/index.php where api folder is in the root folder.

$.ajax({
      url: "/api/index.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'form_email': this.state.contactEmail,
        'form_msg': this.state.contactMessage
      },

But when I'm submitting form getting 404 error. "Cannot POST /api/index.php"

I need help to call php file via ajax or other method to submit form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the type: 'POST' to method: 'POST'